# I want to only return the most recent/max value from a set in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

I have a list of clients with a `Payment ID` that has changed over the years, but I'm only interested in returning the info from the most recent.  This is my result after running:

```sql
     Select distinct 
    a.client 
    , a.payment_id 
    , max(a.update_year_month)  
    from Client_Data a

    group by 1,2
```

| Client | Payment ID | Update Year_Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 202005 |
| A | C | 201907 |
| A | D | 201706 |

I only want my query to pull in the most recent one regardless of the `payment_id`.  However, I need to still bring in `Payment ID` for my larger query.

Comment: To be clear, there are thousands of clients in this table and I need to most recent payment ID for each of them without bringing in the older payment IDs

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
select 
    a.client 
  , a.payment_id 
  , max(a.update_year_month)
from Client_Data a
group by 1
```

or

```
select 
    a.client 
  , a.payment_id 
  , a.update_year_month
from Client_Data a
where a.update_year_month 
      = (select max(b.update_year_month)
          from Client_Data b where a.client = b.client)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified.  There are thousands of clients in this table.  And I want to get the most recent payment ID for each one and not bring in any of the older Payment IDs.

Comment: Oh, does the updated version do what you want?

Comment: I have to group payment_id or it has to be in an aggregate function.. I don't know if that is a netezza specific issue or not.

Comment: Yes must be netezza; my query works in SQLite.

Comment: I added a second query that uses a correlated subquery that also works in SQLite

Comment: I ended up just making a table without the payment_id and the max update_year_month then joining in the same table.  Thanks for your help!